# How do you update the state of a riverpod Future provider via a method

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a futureProvider that watching the stream of AuthStateChanges and adjusts its state accordingly, but I also want to be able to manually control the state but I can use a method because its telling me the type if future, I have also tried using a Future method with async and it still doesn't work. so how do you use methods to control the state of a FutureProvider?

```
enum LoginTypes {
  NotSignedIn,
  Anonymous,
  AppleNoEmail,
  LoggedInEmail,
}

@riverpod
class LoginType extends _$LoginType {
  @override
  Future<LoginTypes> build() async {
    final userAuthState = ref.watch(userAuthProvider);
    print('Stream being called from loginType');

    return userAuthState.when(
      data: (user) async {
        if (user == null) {
          return LoginTypes.NotSignedIn;
        } else {
          try {
            // Access the Firestore collection for users
            CollectionReference userCollection =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

            // Retrieve the document with the given UID
            DocumentSnapshot userDocument =
                await userCollection.doc(user.uid).get();

            // Check if the document exists
            if (userDocument.exists) {
              // Retrieve and return the user's email
              String? userEmail = userDocument.get('email') as String?;
              print(userEmail);

              if (userEmail == 'anom@gmail.com') {
                return LoginTypes.Anonymous;
              } else if (userEmail == 'apple@gmail.com') {
                return LoginTypes.AppleNoEmail;
              } else {
                return LoginTypes.LoggedInEmail;
              }
            }

            return LoginTypes.NotSignedIn;
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error checking user type: $e');
            return LoginTypes.NotSignedIn;
          }
        }
      },
      loading: () => LoginTypes.NotSignedIn,
      error: (_, __) => LoginTypes.NotSignedIn,
    );
  }

  void setToEmail() {
    state = LoginTypes.LoggedInEmail;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question which was posted 2 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940287/how-to-use-firebase-authstatechanges-to-control-a-riverpod-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the value with [`AsyncData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncData-class.html).

```dart
void setToEmail() {
  state = AsyncData(LoginTypes.LoggedInEmail);
}
```

See:

- [Updating our local cache to match the API response](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/side_effects#updating-our-local-cache-to-match-the-api-response)
- [AsyncData class](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncData-class.html)

Comment: This answer allowed the code to run but for some reason running that method did not manage to change my state, I called it like this:  ref.read(loginTypeProvider.notifier).setToEmail();

Comment: I believe it has to be synced with what the reactive `build` returns, so using manual state change like this is only used to update the provider faster (without the need to wait for the future inside `build` to complete), not to override its reactivity. So you need to somehow find a way that the `build` method will respect the forced state change

Comment: thank you, I will try some logic with passing a parameter